# How can I remove frames from an animated gif file in Java?

Tags: java, image

I have some animated gifs (of anagrams rearranging since you ask) that I'd like to remove the final n frames from. Is there any Java utility that will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you need to code that yourself, maybe use
https://github.com/rtyley/animated-gif-lib-for-java
as a library to access and save frames